# Extracting undelimited strings and integers using Boost Spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, peg

I'm trying to convert a string like `"ABC10DEF20"` to an array `["ABC", 10, "DEF", 20]` using Boost Spirit. I'm not sure if "undelimited" is the right term but I want to break it up by the boundaries of integers and non-integers rather than splitting it by whitespace or another delimiting character.

I've come up with code like:

```
std::string search_str = "ABC10DEF20";
std::vector<boost::variant<std::string, unsigned int> > v;
std::string::const_iterator iter = search_str.begin();
std::string::const_iterator last = search_str.end();

bool r = parse(iter, last,
               +(+(char_ - digit)|uint_),
               v);
```

For the input `"ABC10DEF20"` this results in `[ 65, 66, 67, 10, 68, 69, 70, 20 ]` (no strings, just the integers and ASCII components of the string portion stored in integers).  For the input `"10"` I get `[ 10 ]` as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the output, it's apparent you're matching individual characters, not strings, and full unsigned integers.

Not sure it'll fix it, but try:

```
bool r = parse(iter, last,
               +(+(+char_ - digit)|uint_),
               v);
```

(Note the added `+` before `char_`.)

The type of `v` might need to change to be:
`std::vector<boost::variant<std::vector<char>, unsigned int> > v;`, and you might have to fixup the result. Not terribly familiar with Boost Spirit; I bet there's a better, cleaner, way.

**Final Solution:**

Modify the parse expression to use:

```
+(as_string[+(char_ - digit)]|uint_)
```

Comment: Making the rule change results in `[ 65, 66, 67, 49, 48, 68, 69, 70, 50, 48 ]` so it's actually worse because now even the integers are coming in as ASCII characters.

Comment: Also, +char_ should convert to std::string just fine. The Boost Spirit docs do it several times.

Comment: What if you prioritize `digit`?  i.e. `digit - +char_`?

Comment: Well that's actually part of a "but not" operator so the swapping the order wouldn't make sense. Right now its "chars but not digit chars". Swapping them would mean "match digit chars but not any char" (so it'd match nothing).

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry, like I said, not terribly familiar with spirit.  But now that you've said that, it seems operator precedence might be factoring into this. What about `+((+(char_ - digit))|uint_)`?

Comment: You're `vector<char>` made me second guess what I was doing which led to me finding `as_string` which is what I should have been using to coerce it into a string type. It all works now. The final form is `+(as_string[+(char_ - digit)]|uint_)`.  If you want to amend your answer with that I can mark this answered. Thanks for bouncing some ideas off with me.

Comment: Done. Glad to have been of some marginal utility. :)